# is this is right way to make choice in c++ while we have to choose one from option?

Tags: c++, project

```
case 1:
    cout<<"what is the name of our country. \n A. india \t\t B. africa \n C.australia \t\t D.america\n";
    if(toupper(getchar()) == 'A' ) // **is this is right way?**
       {

        cout<<"correct. \n you win $100000\n"; count++;
        getch();
        break;
    }
    else
```

Comment: No it isn't. You need to capture the input in a variable so you can compare it against several values, or you need to use a switch statement which can pick among several alternatives simultaneously.

Comment: @john can you show it me by code?

Comment: IMO question is incomplete. To provide usable answer more context is needed.

Comment: Are you attempting to make a quiz that is composed of multiple multiple-choice questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO but this works

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a;
cout<<"what is the name of our country. \n A. india \t\t B. africa \n C.australia \t\t D.america\n";
cin>>a;
if (a== 'A') cout<<"correct. \n you win $100000\n";
if (a== 'B') cout<<"Welcome to Africa\n";


    return 0;
}
```